# less css not working properly on server

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, less

So I recently bought a theme that uses less css, I tested it on my local wamp server and everything worked fine in ie chrome and chrome mobile.

I then proceeded to upload it to my online server and everything worked fine in chrome, ie and then when I tested it on chrome mobile it didn't load the css, but if I use opera mobile on the same phone it loads fine, so clearly the fault is with the server but not sure what the problem could be,

Any suggestions, ?

Comment: Do you have any type of caching on the page that may be preventing the new css?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file on your web server to check if there is any kind of caching enabled,

If there is you need to remove these data stores / caches so that the browser downloads the new content rather than rendering the cached (old) version of the CSS.

To do this on chrome select **Chrome** and the **Clear Browsing Data**

p.s. Its worth trying this even if you .htaccess draws a null just to be sure...